# Linq order by with cast as

Tags: c#, linq

So I have an object the inherits a list.

```
public class Foo: List<Bar>
```

And I want to reorder it by `BarDate` which is a property on `Bar`

For example

```
Foo testFoo = GetFoo();

testFoo = testFoo.OrderBy(b => b.BarDate).ToList();
```

but `testFoo` is of type `Foo` not `List` so how could I do the cast?

Thanks

Comment: I just ran this code and it worked fine. It shouldn't be a problem because `Foo` implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`. What error message are you getting?

Comment: It works? I get a compiler error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Bar>' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Foo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. You are setting a reference to a derived class an instance of its base which won't work.

The reference `testFoo` can only be a `Foo` or an object derived from `Foo` (`List<Bar>` is a base class of `Foo`)

You can, however, do something like this:

```
public class Foo : List<Bar>
{
    public Foo()
    {}

    public Foo(IEnumerable<Bar> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {}
}
```

And in your code later on:

```
Foo testFoo = new Foo();
testFoo = new Foo(testFoo.OrderBy(b => b.BarDate));
```

The LINQ expression will return an `IEnumerable<Bar>`, so is compatible with one of the constructors of `List<T>`

Incidentally, the reason the compiler error message says "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" is because if you have an object that really is a `Foo` that happens to be referenced as a `List<Bar>` then you can cast it. e.g.

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
List<Bar> myList = myFoo;
Foo sameFoo = (Foo)myList;
```

All three references (`myFoo`, `myList`, and `sameFoo`) all reference the exact same `Foo` instance and casting will work. However, if this is the scenario:

```
List<Bar> actualList = new List<Bar>();
Foo listedFoo = (Foo)actualList;
```

Then the cast will fail because `actualList` isn't a `Foo` or derivative of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` returns a new `List<Bar>`. There is not way of getting a `Foo` object back.
That is one of the reasons you should not inherit from `List`.

Comment: I'm not really sure that is "one of the reasons you should not inherit from List". There may be many good reasons to inherit from List, including adding additional functionality that isn't in List. But if you want your Foo object back (which you were never going to get, because if you stuck with List you were never going to get your original List back, only a new List) then just don't lose the reference to it.

Comment: List hasn't virtual methods to override, so this is of no use. If you add new fields they are Lost in a case like the poster had, because LINQ doesn't return your old List object, only the Elements of it.

Comment: In this case its incredibly useful for me to inherit from a list but I get your point

Comment: Why is it incredible useful for you to inherit from List? Iam sure there are better ways depending on your needs.